# Conditional return from method in scala

Tags: scala

I am a java developer and an trying to conditionally return from a method in scala.

```
def parseDates: Boolean = {

  var date = aoc4Xml \\ "FinancialStmtFromDate" text
  if (StringUtils.isEmpty(date)) {
    addErrorStringFromString("Please enter the financial year start date")
    return false
  }
  aoc4Dto.finYearStartDate = DateUtils.getDateFromFormatOfString(date)

  date = aoc4Xml \\ "FinancialStmtToDate" text
  if (StringUtils.isEmpty(date)) {
    addErrorStringFromString("Please enter the financial year end date")
    return false
  }
  aoc4Dto.finYearEndDate = DateUtils.getDateFromFormatOfString(date)

  true
}
```

This does not compile, at the first if block saying illegal start of expression. How do I implement the above where returning early from a method was considered the best way to handle things.

Just to clarify things:
The above problem technically reduces to

```
def test(testString:String) = {
if(testString == "Chennai"){
  println("correct")
  return true
}

println("outside if")

false
}


test("Chennai")
```

The above will not compile at line return true. There is no problem with the first xml xpath and text.. please ignore all of it and check the conditional return from the method.

Comment: `\\\` is this a valid operator. If so where is it defined?

Comment: its a part of the xml jar of the scala sdk.. please ignore the \\ .. How do conditional returns work.. If you would like read about xml xpath with scala - http://alvinalexander.com/scala/basic-xml-xpath-searching-in-scala

Comment: You've wrongly written `text` it seems . Try removing `text` from `xpath`

Comment: Please check my updated question.. thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time please submit codes without the need to stubb a lot of functionality. The stabbed snipeet, that compiles:

```
object StringUtils{
  def isEmpty(s: String) = true
}

object aoc4Xml{
  def \\(s: String) = {
    new {def text = "test"}
  }
}

object DateUtils{
  def getDateFromFormatOfString(s: String) = 0
}

object Main {
  val date = "date"
  def addErrorStringFromString(s: String) = println(s)
  object aoc4Dto{
    var finYearStartDate = 0
    var finYearEndDate = 0
  }

  def parseDates: Boolean = {
    var date = (aoc4Xml \\ "FinancialStmtFromDate" text)
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(date)) {
      addErrorStringFromString("Please enter the financial year start date")
      return false
    }
    aoc4Dto.finYearStartDate = DateUtils.getDateFromFormatOfString(date)

    date = (aoc4Xml \\ "FinancialStmtToDate" text)
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(date)) {
      addErrorStringFromString("Please enter the financial year end date")
      return false
    }
    aoc4Dto.finYearEndDate = DateUtils.getDateFromFormatOfString(date)

    true
  }
}
```

The difference(just enclose with bracers):

```
var date = (aoc4Xml \\ "FinancialStmtFromDate" text)
date = (aoc4Xml \\ "FinancialStmtToDate" text)
```

And your second snippet has another error:

```
def test(testString:String): Boolean = {
  if(testString == "Chennai"){
    println("correct")
    return true
  }

  println("outside if")

  false
}
```

just provide returning type:

```
def test(testString:String): Boolean = {
```

Comment: thanks for this.... If you paste the above on a scala worksheet and click on run, it will tell you that it fails to compile at line if (StringUtils.isEmpty(date)).. are you facing this too?

Comment: i pasted a reduced problem subsequently.. could you check that too please?

Comment: Also for the brackets, the IDE warns me that its unnecessary and I agree. Its not needed.

Comment: no, the first snippet compiles without errors. Just add surrounding brackets to your first version

Comment: you are right!.. sorry man.. the Intellij Idea plugin for scala still needs some work I guess..